# How do modern browsers deal with the viewport tag? And do I really need it?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, viewport

Suppose I have the following markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background: yellow; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 1100px;">
<head> 
<!--
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=2200, initial-scale=1">        
-->
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container" style="width: 400px; background: red;">
        <div style="background: green; width: 300px; height: 200px;">

             Here goes my text Here goes my text Here goes my text Here goes my text Here goes my text Here goes my text Here goes my text Here goes my text Here goes my text Here goes my text Here goes my text Here goes my text Here goes my text Here goes 
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have set fixed width `1100px` to `html` element. Now when I open this document in google chrome responsive device toolbar and try to decrease the width of the screen then after I go down below 1100px then the whole website starts to *squeeze*. If I do this

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=2200, initial-scale=1">`

Then the website starts squuezing at below 2200px, irrespective of the width of `html` and other `elements`. Does the `width=2200` of `viewport tag` forces the browser to think that `html` tag has width `2200px` so it should start squeezing at below `2200px`?

Comment: I have made the question more specific. *"Does the width=2200 of viewport tag forces the browser to think that html tag has width 2200px so it should start squeezing at below 2200px?"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this time my understanding is correct.

Every browser renders every webpage on it's *viewport*. On desktop screens the viewport is same as the browser window. But on mobile viewport is different in width and height from browser's width and height respectively. To elaborate why it is so consider the first case:

**html document width is 800 css pixels:** Suppose we want to open this webpage on iPhone5. iPhone 5 has width 320 css pixels. Now to show the 800px wide webpage what it does is, it first hypothetically acts like a desktop screen 980 css px wide. It renders the 800px wide page on this imaginary screen. Let us call this imaginary screen the *viewport*. Now iPhone 5 shrinks this imaginary screen by a factor of 320/980, i.e. a div of width 490 css pixels will act like a div of `490 * (320/980) = 160px` -- half of iPhone's screen. Not only div's the text's font size too will be decreased by the same factor. Now let's move onto next case.

**html document width is 1170 css pixels:** Suppose again we want to open this webpage on iPhone5. This time iPhone cannot render the webpage on 980 css px wide viewport. In general whwnever the webpage is larger than 980 css px, the iPhone will render the page on an imaginary screen of the same width as that of the webpage. So this time the iPhone creates it's viewport 1170 css px wide. After that it shrinks the viewport by `320/1170` and renders this page on it's screen. Everything including font sizes is reduced by the same factor.

Now let's get back to the specific question asked in the question.

> Does the width=2200 of viewport tag forces the browser to think that html tag has width 2200px so it should start squeezing at below 2200px?

No, it forces the **mobile(tablet)** browser to think that **viewport's min-width is 2200 css px wide**. Now when I make google chrome responsive tool bar wider than 2200px, say 2400px then the viewport also becomes 2400px wide, it doesn't shrink the webpage when responsive toolbar is wider than 2200px. When the toolbar goes below 2200 it immedeately starts squeezing the vieport because the mnimum width of the viewport is 2200px.

Answer (score -2):

Surprisingly, what viewport tag actually acheives is that it enables the media queries on the webpage. If I had use the following media query with the media query along withe the viewport tag:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
            * {
                width: 200px !important;
            }
        }
```

then the wepage won't squeeze on screen sizes less than 800px. Note that the media query without the viewport tag does nothing below 800px. So what browsers usually do is that if they see the webpage having larger width than the viewport width then they squeeze the webpage -- which is good. The viewport tag is not supposed to stop this inner ability of browsers -- but somehow stops the browser to squeeze at below **980px** and make it squeeze only when viewport width gets smaller than webpage width.. It allows us to use media queries, through which we could imploy different width to different elements. It also provides other functionalities like disallowing user to zoom--in/out by `user-scalabilty`, changing apperant viewport size etc.